# Removing clone <div> without any data left on main <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, clone

Before:
[image: div row 1]

After add a new row and remove that new row.
[image: div row 2]

Why it could be like this? Suppose that when I set val(""), should be there is no value inside that texbox.  **Which part of my code that is wrong?**  Please help.

Below is my code:

```
 <div id="rows" class="block">
            <div class="p2">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" runat="server"/>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox32" runat="server"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="p3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox31" runat="server" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="p5">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p6">
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox26" runat="server"/> 
                &nbsp;
                <span style="color:red;">*</span>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="bttns" class="block" style="text-align:center;">
                <button class="clsButton" id="addrow" >Add Row</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="clsButton" id="remove">Remove Row</button>
            </div>
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
 <script>
 var cloneCount = 1;
 //add new row
  $("#addrow").click(function () {
    $('#rows')
      .clone(true).val("")
      .attr('id', 'rows' + cloneCount++, 'class', 'block')
      .insertAfter('[id^=rows]:last');
      return false;
   });

 //remove row
 $(document).on('click', '#remove', function(){
   $('#rows' + cloneCount).remove();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `$('#rows' + --cloneCount).remove();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mhoe7zb/1/ - post the generated html instead of the asp template

Comment: One problem is you are calling `.val()` on the `div` element not on the `input` elements

Comment: wow, looks great! thanks @arun.

Comment: @arun, i applied already your solution. It works very well. But it didnt delete the row one by one like what happen in https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mhoe7zb/1/ . Do you know the reason why or do you have any other ways for that remove button?

Comment: did you change the delete to `$('#rows' + --cloneCount).remove();`

Comment: I know the reason already. Thanks @arun

Comment: I change $('#rows' + --cloneCount).remove(); already. and I add return false; so that I enable to delete new row one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Arun answer, below is my code;

```
 var cloneCount = 1;
    //Add new row
    $("#addrow").click(function () {
        $('#rows')
          .clone(true).find('input:text').val("").end()
          .attr('id', 'rows' + cloneCount++, 'class', 'block')
          .insertAfter('[id^=rows]:last');
        return false;
    });

    //Remove new row
    $(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
        $('#rows' + --cloneCount).remove();
        return false;
    });
```

and I did some changes on textbox from asp textbox into input type=text.